# I created a Python Function to calcualte the duplicate words but it's not working

Tags: python

I created the function below to calculate the duplicate words in the Pandas Dataframe, but this is taking too long time to process the 1920 rows. Can you please suggest some alternative function here? Actually I started my coding journey a few month back only.

```
wordList =[A,B,C,A,D,E,F]

df['Duplicate Words'] = ''

for i in range(0,len(df.wordList)):
    df['Duplicate Words'][i] = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(df.wordList[i]).items() if count > 1]
```

Expected output : 2

Comment: I see you are expecting the output: `2`. What is the actual output?

Comment: The Actual O/P is also 2 but the problem is if I use a large data frame then it Hangs and display the error : " A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame "

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: why not use directly DataFrame to count words - `df['words'].value_counts()` - instead of `collections.Counter()`

Comment: Hi Pal, 
I am getting the below error while executing the code : TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
Code executed (the below column "Split_merged_Title_WSW_Title_WSW_1" is a part of data frame result_1 ):

Split_merged_Title_WSW_Title_WSW_1 = [upgrade, latest, version, upgrade, latest, version]

result_1['test'] = result_1['Split_merged_Title_WSW_Title_WSW_1'].value_counts()

// I m creating a new col in data frame test and trying to count to  words.

Also tried with below code : Same error.
result_1['test'] = result_1[result_1['Split_merged_Title_WSW_Title_WSW_1'].duplicated()]

Answer (score 1):

I would use `.value_counts()` directly in `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

wordList = ['A','B','C','A','D','E','F']

df = pd.DataFrame({'words': wordList})

count_words = df['words'].value_counts()

duplicate_words = count[ count > 1 ]

print(duplicate_words)
```

Result:

```
A    2
Name: words, dtype: int64
```

---

And if you needs only duplicated words without count then there is `df.duplicated()`

```
duplicate_words = df[ df['words'].duplicated() ]

print(duplicate_words)
```

Result: (number `3` is row index with last `A`, not count)

```
  words
3     A
```

---

`DataFrame` uses code created in C/C++ so I expect it should work faster then Python code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```py
some = 'oOjULPJ97AdkSOwrwE1LobgbQhv9bIVPeCNR8HQi33ZRUrHuyReg9Rw198TeHsEx0KTSwwt2exj1dXztFGR1Cjft5F3LXPUUbmMJ'
data = {
    'first':list(some)
}
test = pd.DataFrame(data)
out = {}
for i in set(test['first'].to_list()):
    if test['first'].to_list().count(i) > 1:
        out[i] = test['first'].to_list().count(i)

print(out)
>>>{'o': 2, 't': 3, 'w': 5, 'r': 2, 'X': 2, 'S': 2, 'O': 2, 'R': 5, 'U': 4, 'F': 2, 'x': 2, '1': 4, 'e': 4, 'C': 2, 'd': 2, '3': 3, 'j': 3, 'b': 4, 'H': 3, 'L': 3, 'g': 2, '8': 2, 'T': 2, 'P': 3, '9': 4, 'Q': 2, 'E': 2, 'J': 2}
```

**EDIT**

Or one string expression:
`out = {i:test['first'].to_list().count(i) for i in set(test['first'].to_list()) if test['first'].to_list().count(i) > 1}`

If you want to find only some words replace `set` to `['your', 'wordlist']`